# The adjoint representation of a Lie group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, equivariant-homotopy

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\text{Ad}(G)$ denote its adjoint representation i.e. the adjoint action of the group $G$ on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. The adjoint representation is a real $G$-representation.

**Question 1**: What are some examples of Lie groups $G$ such that $\text{Ad}(G)$ is a representation of complex type? What I mean by 'representation of complex type' is that along with being a $G$-representation of real type, there exists an endomorphism $J:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}$, such $J^2=-1$ and $J$ commutes with the adjoint action of $G$.

**Question 2**: What about examples, when the underlying group $G$ is a compact Lie group?

PS - An obvious restriction on the choice of such a $G$ would be that it would have to be even dimensional as $\text{dim}(G)=\text{dim}(\mathfrak{g})$. Any example of families of such groups or literature recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this just those groups that have chiral representations, $SU(N)$ and $SO(4k+2)$?

Comment: @Buzz Your first example is even dimensional only when $N$ is odd, and your second example is never even dimensional.

Comment: Is $G$ a compact Lie group? The title says compact but the body doesn't.

Comment: You take a complex algebraic group $G'$ and consider Weil's restriction of scalars $G=R_{{\Bbb C}/{\Bbb R}}G'$. Then the adjoint representation of $G$ is of complex type. But this group $G$ is never compact.

Comment: For a *compact* group $G$, the adjoint representation is never of complext type.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, I have made the necessary edits. The Lie group need not be compact. However, what you have said about the adjoint representation of a compact group is interesting, could you refer me to some material that describes that result?

Comment: Concerning your edited question: I have answered it in a comment.

Comment: Concerning compact groups: I don't know any material. Ask a separate question, and I will answer it. Or better, edit your question so that there will be Question 1 (for not necessary compact group) and Question 2 (about compact groups), and I will answer both questions.

Answer (score 6):

For **Question 2**, there are only two kinds of such examples: the case where $G$ is commutative and even-dimensional, and the case where all simple factors of $G$ come in isomorphic pairs.  (In the former case, the action of $G$ is trivial, so we may arbitrarily put a complex structure on $\DeclareMathOperator\Lie{Lie}\Lie(G)$.  In the latter case, for each pair of isomorphic simple factors $G_1$ and $G_2$, given any choice of $G$-equivariant isomorphism $J_{12} : \Lie(G_1) \to \Lie(G_2)$, we may (uniquely) choose $J_{21} = -J_{12}^{-1}$, and then piece these various maps together to make $J$.)

If we are not in either of those cases, then there is some simple factor of $G$ whose Lie algebra is preserved by $J$, so it suffices to consider $G$ (compact and) simple.  Then the adjoint representation is absolutely irreducible, so there is at most one $G$-invariant bilinear form, up to scalars.  The Killing form $\kappa$ is a non-$0$, real-valued such form, and $\kappa_J \mathrel{:=} \kappa(J\cdot, \cdot)$ is another, so $\kappa_J$ equals $\lambda\kappa$ for some real scalar $\lambda$.  But then $-\kappa = \kappa_{J^2}$ equals $\lambda\kappa_J = \lambda^2\kappa$, so $\lambda^2$ equals $-1$, which is a contradiction.

In the direction of **Question 1** (though not answering it), the same argument ruling out complex-type adjoint representations works for any semisimple, linear Lie group $G$, as long as its simple factors are absolutely simple, and do not come in isomorphic pairs.  A simple factor may instead be (the group of $\mathbb R$-points of) the restriction of scalars of that marvellous combination of adjectives, a simple, complex algebraic group, in which case, as @MikhailBorovoi points out in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457310/the-adjoint-representation-of-a-lie-group/457322#comment1184519_457310), the adjoint representation on the corresponding factor of the Lie algebra will be of complex type.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $V$ is an irreducible real representation of any group $G$, and it has an operator $J$ commuting with $G$ and satisfying $J^2=-Id$.

Suppose $V_\mathbb C=V\otimes\mathbb C$ is irreducible. Then $J_\mathbb C=J\otimes\mathbb C$ commutes with the action of $G$; so by Schur's Lemma $J_\mathbb C$ is a scalar; then $J^2=-I\Rightarrow J_\mathbb C=i*Id$. But then $J$ does not preserve the real vector space $V$, a contradiction. So $V$ cannot be "real" according to your definition. (This is more or less @LSpice's argument, emphasizing it has nothing to do with the adjoint representation.)

In the case of the adjoint representation of a simple Lie group $G$, $V_\mathbb C$ fails to be irreducible precisely when $G$ is the restriction of scalars as discussed by @MikhaelBorovoi and @LSpice. (BTW you probably should say $G$ is semisimple, for example you surely don't want $G$ to be abelian.)

I think the terminology "complex type" for a representation on a real vector space is not standard, and potentially confusing. Usually we talk about a representation on a *complex* vector space being *real* or *quaternionic*, having to do with an anti-holomorphic map $J$ with $J^2=-1$. If I'm wrong I'm sure someone will correct me.

Comment: What is confusing? "Complex type" means exactly that $V$ admits a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space structure compatible with its existing $\mathbb{R}$-vector space structure. This is exactly what "quaternionic type" means also. Actually it is "real type" that's the confusing one since that one has to do with descent data.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457310/the-adjoint-representation-of-a-lie-group#comment1184690_457380), I am confused.  Doesn't "real type" mean just "not complex or quaternionic type"?  To view it as being a matter of descent data seems to require that we be dealing in the first place with complex representations, at which point we wouldn't be discussing their possibly complex type.  (Or perhaps you mean that one discusses the complex-typeness only of real representations, and the real-typeness only of complex representations?)

Comment: Fair enough. I withdraw the objection.